# How to get 2 transactions from same person on a limited time range on microsoft sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get any transaction that happen to the same user within 2 minutes of each other on Microsoft SQL Server

I've based myself on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123687/multiple-transactions-within-a-certain-time-period-limited-by-date-range) to try to solve my problem, and ended up with this query:

```
SELECT css.*
FROM
(
    SELECT css.*,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM CashlessTransactions t2
    WHERE t2.IdCustomerSmartcard = css.IdCustomerSmartcard
          AND t2.IdCashlessTransaction <> css.IdCashlessTransaction
          AND t2.Date >= css.Date
          AND t2.Date < DATEADD(minute, 2, css.Date)
) tranwithin2min
    FROM CashlessTransactions css
) css
JOIN [dbo].[POSDevices] pd ON pd.IdPOSDevice = css.IdPOSDevice
JOIN [dbo].[EventSessionSetups] ess ON ess.IdEventSessionSetup = pd.IdEventSessionSetup
JOIN [dbo].[Events] e ON e.IdEvent = ess.IdEvent
WHERE e.IdEvent = 2
      AND tranwithin2min > 0
ORDER BY css.Date;
```

Problems are:
1- I don't fully understand how this works, so results are not what I expect -> When there's a match for 2 transactions on this period, I get only 1 of them. I've tried messing around, adding some filters and removing others, but couldn't get the result I wanted

2- Query is taking a long time to run. I think its getting the subquery from all cashless transactions, which is a lot, before doing the where IdEvent = 2, which would narrow a lot the search

Edit 1: added data sample:

```
IdCashlessTransaction                 IdCustomerSmartcard                   Amount  Date                    IdPOSDevice
4DA8FA70-905F-44B3-8513-26F4A9AFD212    364DBAA2-E85D-45C3-A4DC-7549A4E7ECE5    10.00     2017-02-23 18:18:50.000   D3E5452E-4DAB-4B4D-B64D-24599DDA7A49
0B486470-2CB6-4145-8BA5-5B54AABEF997    364DBAA2-E85D-45C3-A4DC-7549A4E7ECE5    0.00      2017-02-23 18:18:51.000   D3E5452E-4DAB-4B4D-B64D-24599DDA7A49
8B156710-29CF-4104-B669-63A004F1B19B    364DBAA2-E85D-45C3-A4DC-7549A4E7ECE5    -9.79     2017-02-23 18:19:06.000   D3E5452E-4DAB-4B4D-B64D-24599DDA7A49
```

Edit 2: added requested DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CashlessTransactions](
  [IdCashlessTransaction] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [IdUser] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [IdCustomerSmartcard] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [IdPOSDevice] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
  [Amount] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
  [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_POSTransactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [IdCashlessTransaction] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data? That case where there's a match for 2 transactions and only 1 gets returned would be a good sample.

Comment: Also, can you provide the DDL for the `CashlessTransactions` table?

Comment: If transaction1 happens at time X, and transaction2 happens at time X+90 seconds, and transaction 3 happens at time X+180 seconds, do you want all three transactions returned, or some combination of just two of them?

Comment: @digital.aaron, I've added data sample, but I'm not sure what is DDL

Comment: @digital.aaron I'd either want the 3 of them, or 4 with the middle one repeated, to be split on two sets

Comment: DDL stands for Data Definition Language, and in this context it means the `CREATE TABLE` statement used to create the `CashlessTransactions` table. It includes things like the column names and data types.

Comment: @digital.aaron I've added what you wanted, I think, removing some tables that weren't relevant on this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What the query is doing for each transaction is getting a count of different transactions made with the same card, within 2 minutes of the original transaction. It gets this count for each transaction in the main query. It then returns each transaction that has at least 1 other transaction that happened within 2 minutes of the first. So for your three sample records, the first tran (tran1) comes back with a count of 2 (since the next two trans are within 2 minutes). The next tran (tran2) comes back with a count of 1, because only the last transaction in the list is within 2 minutes of tran2. The last transaction is not returned because the count is 0 (there are no trans that come after it), and thus is filtered out by the `WHERE`.

2) If you only care about transactions that have an IdEvent of 2, you'll need to join to `POSDevices`, `EventSessionSetups`, and `events` twice.

Here's what I came up with. You can change the columns being returned in by the main `SELECT`, and I encourage you to change the `css.*` in the `LEFT JOIN` subquery to only return the columns you need in the main `SELECT`.

```
SELECT 
    UsersCardID             = c1.IdCustomerSmartcard 
    ,OriginalTransaction    = c1.IdCashlessTransaction
    ,OrigTranDate           = c1.Date
    ,OrigTranAmount         = c1.Amount
    ,TranWithin2Min         = c2.IdCashlessTransaction
    ,TranWithin2MinDate     = c2.Date
    ,TranWithin2MinAmount   = c2.Amount
FROM #CashlessTransactions      c1
JOIN [dbo].[POSDevices]         pd1 ON pd1.IdPOSDevice = c1.IdPOSDevice
JOIN [dbo].[EventSessionSetups] ess1 ON ess1.IdEventSessionSetup = pd1.IdEventSessionSetup
JOIN [dbo].[events]             e1 ON e1.IdEvent = ess1.IdEvent
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                css.*
            FROM CashlessTransactions css
            JOIN [dbo].[POSDevices]         pd2 ON pd2.IdPOSDevice = css.IdPOSDevice
            JOIN [dbo].[EventSessionSetups] ess2 ON ess2.IdEventSessionSetup = pd2.IdEventSessionSetup
            JOIN [dbo].[events]             e2 ON e2.IdEvent = ess2.IdEvent
            WHERE e.IdEvent = 2
) c2 ON c2.IdCustomerSmartcard = c1.IdCustomerSmartcard AND c2.IdCashlessTransaction <> c1.IdCashlessTransaction
WHERE c2.Date >= c1.Date 
    AND c2.Date < DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, c1.Date)
    AND c2.IdCashlessTransaction IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c1.date, c2.date
```

Comment: This is definetly closer to what I want, but I'm getting now duplicated values on those 3 transactions. The first value is coming up twice. I'll try to mess around with it to see if I can fix it

Comment: It comes up twice because there are two other transactions that happened within 2 minutes. the query returns one record per transaction pair.

Comment: So if I had tran1: date = now, tran2: date = now + 1 min, and queried it, I'd get (tran1, tran1, tran2) by design?

Comment: Actually, its just some problem with the label. 'OriginalTransaction' is coming with a duplicated value, even though they are different transactions. When I get to the right way to correct it, I'll edit your answer I guess

Comment: Using the sample data you provided, the transaction with id = `4DA8FA70-905F-44B3-8513-26F4A9AFD212` will appear twice under `OriginalTransaction`. But each of those two records has a different `TranWithin2Min` id. You never said how you wanted your data formatted, and you didn't seem to like having a single record with a count of transactions that come after within 2 minutes, so I had to come up with a format on my own that still makes sense in the context of this problem. Feel free to adapt this code to your needs as you see fit.

Comment: Hadnt paid proper attention to the result, my bad. Thanks for the help