# Find Accounts with X Number of Transactions within Y Days of Each Other in a Larger Date Range

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will find the accounts that have had 3 or more transactions within 3 days whose absolute value is greater than $10.00 over the course of a week and then return those transactions.

Consider this data...

```
TransactionID  AccountNumber  TransactionDate  TransactionAmount
-------------  -------------  ---------------  -----------------
1              0123           2020-09-01       45.75
2              0123           2020-09-02       5.23
3              0123           2020-09-03       9.94
4              0123           2020-09-05       8.35
5              0123           2020-09-06       -16.23
6              0123           2020-09-07       14.71
7              0123           2020-09-08       15.03
8              0123           2020-09-08       23.10
9              0123           2020-09-09       94.20
10             0123           2020-09-09       5.01
11             0123           2020-09-10       3.02
12             0123           2020-09-11       4.37
13             0123           2020-09-12       4.54
14             9876           2020-09-01       -45.75
15             9876           2020-09-02       5.27
16             9876           2020-09-05       19.79
17             9876           2020-09-05       -11.64
18             9876           2020-09-06       12.42
```

If the week under review is 2020-09-01 to 2020-09-07 I would expect only AccountNumber 9876 to fit the criteria with TransactionIDs 16, 17, and 18 being the 3 transactions within 3 days with an absolute value greater than $10.00.

It seems like I should be able to use window functions (and perhaps framing), but I can't figure out how to start.

I have attempted without the use of window functions based on the answers to this question...

[multiple transactions within a certain time period, limited by date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123687/multiple-transactions-within-a-certain-time-period-limited-by-date-range)

```
DECLARE
    @BeginDate       DATE
  , @EndDate         DATE
  , @ThresholdAmount DECIMAL(10, 2)
  , @ThresholdCount  INT
  , @NumberOfDays    INT;

SET @BeginDate = '09/01/2020';
SET @EndDate = '09/07/2020';
SET @ThresholdAmount = 10.00;
SET @ThresholdCount = 3;
SET @NumberOfDays = 3;

SELECT t.*
FROM   (
           SELECT
                 t1.*
               , (
                     SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM   Transactions t2
                     WHERE  t2.AccountNumber   = t1.AccountNumber
                        AND t2.TransactionID   <> t1.TransactionID
                        AND t2.TransactionDate >= t1.TransactionDate
                        AND t2.TransactionDate < DATEADD(DAY, @NumberOfDays, t1.TransactionDate)
                        AND ABS(t2.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
                 ) AS NumberWithinXDays
           FROM  Transactions t1
           WHERE t1.TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
             AND ABS(t1.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
       ) t
WHERE  t.NumberWithinXDays >= @ThresholdCount;

SELECT *
FROM   Transactions t
WHERE  EXISTS (
                  SELECT *
                  FROM   (
                             SELECT     t1.AccountNumber
                             FROM       Transactions t1
                             INNER JOIN Transactions t2 ON t1.AccountNumber = t2.AccountNumber
                                                       AND t1.TransactionID <> t2.TransactionID
                                                       AND DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.TransactionDate, t2.TransactionDate) BETWEEN 0 AND (@NumberOfDays-1)
                             WHERE      t1.TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
                                    AND t2.TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
                                    AND ABS(t1.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
                                    AND ABS(t2.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
                             GROUP BY   t1.AccountNumber
                             HAVING     COUNT(t1.TransactionID) >= @ThresholdCount
                         ) x
                  WHERE  x.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber
              )
   AND t.TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
   AND ABS(t.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
```

My first query comes back with...

```
TransactionID  AccountNumber  TransactionDate  TransactionAmount  NumberWithinXDays
-------------  -------------  ---------------  -----------------  -----------------
5              0123           2020-09-06       -16.23             3
6              0123           2020-09-07       14.71              3
```

Not even close. And the second query returns...

```
TransactionID  AccountNumber  TransactionDate  TransactionAmount
-------------  -------------  ---------------  -----------------
14             9876           2020-09-01       -45.75
16             9876           2020-09-05       19.79
17             9876           2020-09-05       -11.64
18             9876           2020-09-06       12.42
```

Closer, but not restricted to just transaction within 3 days of each other. This is the result I want.

```
TransactionID  AccountNumber  TransactionDate  TransactionAmount
-------------  -------------  ---------------  -----------------
16             9876           2020-09-05       19.79
17             9876           2020-09-05       -11.64
18             9876           2020-09-06       12.42
```

Now it is certainly possible I have not implemented these suggested queries correctly. Or maybe there is some subtle difference I am missing and they just don't fit my situation.

Any suggestions on fixing either of my attempted queries or something completely different with or without window functions?

Here is full [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3c68cfb12c002809a12f9d36f17e85ef) of my code.

Comment: How do you consider the start of a week?  Calendar date? Or the minimum date on the table as starting point?

Comment: I have date calculations that will figure that out. I am actually going to back up the starting date by two days to get the entire 3 day window in my larger date range.

Comment: Based on example data, I would expect transaction (14, 16, 17) and (16, 17, 18) as result - unless I am not understanding the requirement.

Comment: I may be describing the requirement incorrectly. Transactions 14, 16, and 17 do not meet the requirement because they occurred over a span of more than 3 days. Also, my the examples I posted here were not in sync with what I had in the dbfiddle. I have fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to come up with a solution using window functions. As I thought about it more I thought I might be able to use a CTE, but I could not figure that out either.

I solve it using a couple of subqueries. I was concerned about performance given my transaction table has 86 million rows. However, it runs in less than 30 seconds and that is good enough for me.

```
-- distinct is need because a particular transaction may fit into more than 
-- one transaction window but we only want to see it once in the results
SELECT     DISTINCT
           t.TransactionID
         , t.AccountNumber
         , t.TransactionDate
         , t.TransactionAmount
FROM       (
               SELECT
                          t1.AccountNumber
                        , t1.TransactionDateWindowBegin
                        , t1.TransactionDateWindowEnd
                        , COUNT(DISTINCT t2.TransactionID) AS Count
               FROM       (
                              -- establish the transaction window for each transaction within the 
                              -- larger date range and an absolute value above the threshold 
                              SELECT
                                    TransactionID
                                  , AccountNumber
                                  , TransactionDate                                  AS [TransactionDateWindowBegin]
                                  , DATEADD(DAY, @NumberOfDays - 1, TransactionDate) AS [TransactionDateWindowEnd]
                                  , TransactionAmount
                              FROM  Transactions
                              WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
                                AND ABS(TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
                          )             t1
               -- join back to the transaction table to find transactions within the transaction window for 
               -- each transaction, count them, and only keep those that are above the threshold count
               INNER JOIN Transactions t2 ON t1.AccountNumber              = t2.AccountNumber
                                         AND t1.TransactionDateWindowBegin <= t2.TransactionDate
                                         AND t1.TransactionDateWindowEnd   >= t2.TransactionDate
               WHERE      t2.TransactionDate BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
                      AND ABS(t2.TransactionAmount) > @ThresholdAmount
               GROUP BY   t1.AccountNumber
                        , t1.TransactionDateWindowBegin
                        , t1.TransactionDateWindowEnd
               HAVING     COUNT(DISTINCT t2.TransactionID) >= @ThresholdCount
           )             x
-- join back to the transaction table again to get the details for the 
-- transactions that meet the threshold amount and count criteria
INNER JOIN Transactions t ON x.AccountNumber              = t.AccountNumber
                         AND x.TransactionDateWindowBegin <= t.TransactionDate
                         AND x.TransactionDateWindowEnd   >= t.TransactionDate
                         AND ABS(t.TransactionAmount)     > @ThresholdAmount;
```

Here is the full [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=080b8087379b1c2d86233901e7286624).